# VBA macro having issue when looping through and renaming files in folder?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

The following code goes through all PDF files in a folder, gets the first word of the file name and checks excel spreadsheet if the word it exists in a range.If it does not exist, it renames the file and adds the word "uploaded". The issue is that once it goes through all the files in the folder in goes through them again and again. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
Sub checkmissing()
    

    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String,
    Dim ioid As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Show
       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
       Err.clear
    End With

    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\" & "*.pdf")

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        DoEvents
        On Error GoTo 0
        
   ioid = Split(MyFile, " ")(0)
  
    Range("G1").Activate
   

     With ActiveSheet.Range("G1:G10000")
     Set c = .Find(ioid, LookIn:=xlValues)
       If c Is Nothing Then
         Name MyFolder & "\" & MyFile As MyFolder & "\" & "Uploaded " & MyFile
       End If
     End With
  

        ChDir MyFolder
        
0
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: VBA macro with Excel

Comment: remove this `ChDir MyFolder`? I don't think it's necessary. Also, remove `On Error Resume Next`. Then place only 3 files in your folder and test your code by running line-by-line and debugging to see why the infinite loop appears.

Comment: Each renamed file will cause a new Dir result, gets renamed, causes new result ...infinite loop! To avoid store all filesnames in an array and rename after Dir loop or exclude filenames starting with "Uploaded" from renaming!

Comment: I simply just added this and it works now:  `If ioid = "Uploaded" Then
   Exit Sub
   End If`

Comment: Read up on `FSO`. So much more user friendly in my opinion.